# Interacting with C++ objects through Mex files

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I'm a bit stuck on if my current goal is feasible, and if so, how to do this.  I'm hoping to interact with some C++ classes through a Mex file, but I would need the instances of the objects I am accessing to be persistent across calls from different Mex functions.  For example, suppose I do the following within an initialization Mex file:

```
void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    size_t nCats = (size_t) *mxGetPr(prhs[0]);

    std::vector<Cat> cats;
    for(size_t i = 0; i <nCats; i++){
         cats[i] = Cat(/* arguments to constructor*/);
    }
}
```

So I've initialized my Cat objects from my external C++ code.  Now, later down the line, I need to update info about my Cat objects, so in a different Mex file I have

```
void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

     for(size_t i = 0; i < nCats; i++){
          cats[i].feed(/*parameters to feed method*/);
     }
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. How would I make this std::vector persist across calls to *different* Mex files?  There isn't a way to return non-Matlab types from Mex files (that I'm aware of), and Mathworks says that local variables within Mex functions are generally garbage collected when the function returns, which I do not want.  How can I call the same std::vector with the stored objects I am interested in across different functions?   Or even calls to the same function?
2. Is there a better way to do this with Matlab?  Essentially I'm trying to use Matlab to drive some C++ code, which does the heavy lifting, and then brings it all back to Matlab for analysis.  The trouble is that the C++ code is already written, and I need to try to bend Matlab to fit those classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if possible between Mex functions but you can make some things persistent between calls to the same mex routine.

See documentation for:

- [mexMakeMemoryPersistent](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexmakememorypersistent.html)
- [mexMakeArrayPersistent](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexmakearraypersistent.html)

Also see this answer on the Mathworks site:
[How can I make memory persistent between calls to a MEX-file in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103891-how-can-i-make-memory-persistent-between-calls-to-a-mex-file-in-matlab)

I have not done this myself so can't give more specific help but this might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the mexMakePersistent methods will work on non-Matlab objects (which I need to interface with).  I believe simply declaring the needed variables as static will work, though I haven't yet tried with this case.

Comment: I also found [this on Mathworks Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/783-i-have-a-c-class-how-can-i-interface-to-it-through-a-matlab-class#answer_192044).  It references a GitHub Repo.  The design goals sound more closely to what you are looking for.    It does sound a lot more complicated than decarling the variables as static.